# SQL: filter out same record different status

Tags: sql

I am trying to filter out some records but cannot make it.

Take this table as example,

```
ID   Status    Name
1      NULL    ItemA  
2      2       ItemB  
3      2       ItemA  
4      NULL    ItemC
```

I try to show name as result with only NULL status and if for an item with status 2, do not show it. In this case, the result is only `ItemC` because even one record of `ItemA` has NULL status, there is another record of ItemA with status 2.

I am stuck here.

Comment: At the very least, post the desired output based on your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want names all of whose statuses are `NULL`, then you can use aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having max(status) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `except` or `minus` depending on the database being used. Note this doesn't work for MySQL.

```
select * from tablename 
where name in 
(
select name from tablename where status is null
except --minus if you are using Oracle
select name from tablename where status is not null
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Due to my huge query, yours works better.

Answer (score 0):

VKP's answer is better fitting my query but Gordon's answer works just fine.
Thanks again guys.